# PHP show file available for download if it contains $_GET[number]

Tags: php, download, glob

As part of a page I'd like to be able to show files available for download if they contain the GET result number ($_GET[number]). However, what I'm doing doesn't appear to be working, and I'm also not sure it's a particularly secure means of achieving it either. Here's what I'm trying so far (which doesn't display anything at all!):

```
foreach (glob("Files/*$_GET[number]*.*") as $filename) {  
    echo $filename."<br />";  
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, changed the "Files/*$_GET[number]*.*" to 'Files/*$_GET["number"]*.*' but I'm still not getting any files show up for download

Comment: @user2062950: No he doesn't. Actually, adding quotes there (array inside a double-quoted string) would throw an error.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I thought associative array keys must be in quotes at all times..? And yes, the OP will need to break up the string (as my answer mentions)

Comment: @user2062950: -1. That's FALSE. You cannot use quoted array keys inside a double-quoted string like that, UNLESS you're using the `{}` notation. Good: `"$foo[bar]"` and `"{$foo['bar']}"`. Bad: `"$foo['bar']"`.

Comment: @MarcB good to know, removed my comment / answer

Comment: Still getting nothing, run it through the CLI and no errors.. The wildcards I've used, say I have a file named Order/2013-09-03[123456]-etp0001.txt would that work? I'm guessing that could be the issue (where 123456 is the GET result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definatly should check $_GET["number"] if is really and only a number for security reasons.

```
$_GET["number"] = intval($_GET["number"]);
```

Sorry but too low reputation to post this as a comment..

Comment: This actually turned out to be the problem - another part of the script was adding in a '.'! Thanks for solving!